# How can I implement a 2D array with bound cheking in C++ using template more efficiently?

Tags: c++

Now I implement it like this:

```
template <typename T>
class Array2D{
  private:
    T **pointer = nullptr;
    int n1, n2;
    class tmp{
        private:
            T* pointer;
            int n;
        public:
            tmp(T* p, int n):pointer(p),n(n){}
            T& operator[](unsigned int x){
                assert(x<n);
                return pointer[x];
            }
    };
  public:
    Array2D(int n, int m):n1(n), n2(m){
        pointer = new T *[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            pointer[i] = new T[m];
    }
    ~Array2D(){delete[] pointer;}
    tmp&& operator[](unsigned int x){
        assert(x < n1);
        return move(tmp(pointer[x], n2));
    }
};
```

I feel that the code a little bit ugly. The reason why I use tmp class is that if it return T* directly in the class Array2D, it could not check the bounce in the second dimension. So I add a class named temporary. But I feel the effiency get worse for this class.  Is there a better solution?

And another thing confuses me. I want others could use this class only in two dimension form. I mean that if you only use a [] to a instance of this class, you will get an error. So I put class tmp in the private section. But I find it can not work. Is there a solution?

Comment: `std::vector<std::vector<T>>` seems more appropriate.

Comment: You have memory leak, you only delete pointer to array content, but not its content.

Comment: Really? I hear that use delete[] instead of delete will avoid these problems.

Answer (score 2):

The existence of `tmp` is fine, any compiler will optimize these temporary instances away.

Preventing the use of a single `[]` cannot be enforced, but you can trigger warnings by using `[[nodiscard]]` on the return value from `Array2D::operator[]`.

There is, however, a bug in your implementation: you're returning a dangling reference from your `operator[]`. Just do:

```
tmp operator[](unsigned int x){
    assert(x < n1);
    return tmp(pointer[x], n2);
}
```

Finally, you shouldn't go through the hassle of managing the storage's lifetime manually. In fact, there's already several other bugs there: your destructor leaks memory, and your class doesn't obey the rule of 5, so copying or assigning `Array2D`'s will lead to UB. Just use a `std::vector<std::vector<T>>`, or better yet (for contiguity) a single `std::vector<T>` which you split into rows.

Closing note: once your code works and is ready to be shown, you can take it for a walk at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yeah, it is a bug that I can not return the reference. I find this in latter time. But I feel the effeciency is a little bad when I return the whole object. I do not implement codes on copying for the sake of length. I just show the core things here. If so, are there memory leaking bugs?

Comment: The first reason why I don't choose vector<vector<T>> or std::array is that std::vector will allocate a big space first and std::array do not allow dynamic allocating.  The second reason is that the process is fun, isn't it? :)  In fact, in the real codes, I just use traditionally C-like style codes to solve the problem.

Comment: @yodahaji No idea what you mean by "allocate a big space first": `std::vector<T>(n)` allocates exactly as much as `new T[n]`. As for efficiency, optimized binary performance is relevant, vague feelings are not.

Comment: If it allocates exactly as much as new T[n], what will happen when I call push_back(x) n+1 times?

Comment: But you wouldn't call `push_back`, since you already have the elements you need...

Comment: So If I create a class which inherited from std::vector<> and I deleted push_back(), I would make my day:)

Comment: Why not. But you don't really need to do that if you don't expose the vector :)

Answer (score 0):

One option would be not to use the subscript operator at all and just have an `at` function which takes both indexes. This would also be more consistent with the standard library containers which perform bounds checking in the at functions.

For example:

```
template < typename T >
class Array2D
{
public:
    Array2D(size_t m, size_t n)
    : data( m, std::vector< T >( n, T() ) )
    {
    }

    T& at( size_t x, size_t y )
    {
        return data.at( x ).at( y );
    }

    const T& at( size_t x, size_t y ) const
    {
        return data.at( x ).at( y );
    }
private:
    std::vector<std::vector<T>> data;
};
```

Using `std::vector` to store your data gives:

1. fixes rule of 5 bugs
2. manages all memory allocation for you
3. implements the bounds checking for you

The less code you write and the more you rely on the standard library the fewer bugs you'll create (generally).

You can use the subscript operator with a non-integral type, for example if you use `std::pair< size_t, size_t >` you can implement it like this:

```
T& operator [] ( std::pair<size_t, size_t> p )
{
    return data.at( p.first ).at( p.second );
}

T& operator [] ( std::pair<size_t, size_t> p ) const
{
    return data.at( p.first ).at( p.second );
}
```

And call it like this:

```
Array2D< int > a( 10, 20 );
a[{5,5}] = 10;
std::cout << a[{5,5}] << "\n";
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I research the question only for fun in fact. Although I know that a programmer should not create wheel, the process is funny. By the way, what is the rule of 5 bugs? Is it mean there is 5 bugs in my codes? I searched this but not find its meanning.

Comment: The rule of 3 or 5 is that if you've implemented one of 3/5 methods you probably need to implement them all, see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three

Comment: It's really helpful!